# "ORA-00922: missing or invalid option" when creating tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I entered the following SQL commands in Oracle but it complained "ORA-00922: missing or invalid option"

```
CREATE TABLE Student (
    StuID     NUMBER(15),
    StuName   VARCHAR2(50),
    Phone     VARCHAR2(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (StuID))

CREATE TABLE Program (
    ProCode       VARCHAR2(12),
    ProTitle      VARCHAR2(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (ProCode))
```

WHY???

Comment: Did you try create only one table at a time to narrow the problem? Maybe it's because you're missing `;` between those to `create table` statements?

Comment: No. Adding the semicolons gets error like "invalid character"

Comment: @Steven Odd, gives exact same error on my Oracle, adding semicolons makes it work. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87f1e

Comment: Maybe you allready have this table defined? try replace `CREATE TABLE` with `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE`

Comment: @gdoron I'm sure no tables were previously defined >_<

Comment: @gdoron: there is no create or replace table in Oracle. I agree with Joachim Isaksson: it's the missing `;` at the end of the statements.

Comment: NO. adding the `;` gets error! "invalid character"
The problem is that if I run the statements one by one and it's fine; but failed if I run them the same time! why?

Comment: @Steven: which tool do you use to run this? If it's the dreaded HTML GUI (inside the browser) of OracleXE then that does not support running more than one statement. Use SQL Developer or any other GUI tool instead.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name OH WTF! I'm using this!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using the dreaded HTML GUI (inside the browser) of OracleXE then that does not support running more than one statement.

Use SQL Developer, SQL*Plus or any other GUI tool instead.

Answer (score 6):

```
CREATE TABLE Student (
    StuID     NUMBER(15),
    StuName   VARCHAR2(50),
    Phone     VARCHAR2(20),
    CONSTRAINT PK_STUID PRIMARY KEY (StuID))
```

Found the answer [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190305005935/http://www.sqlinfo.net/oracle/oracle_Create_table.php).

**Edit:**

Also, try using `/` as a statement separator, instead of a `;`

Answer (score 1):

Try no to define the size of StuID.
also add constraint key work
and just to make sure use DROP before CREATE
like this:

```
DROP TABLE Student;

CREATE TABLE Student (
    StuID     NUMBER,
    StuName   VARCHAR2(50),
    Phone     VARCHAR2(20),
    constraint pk_Student PRIMARY KEY (StuID));

DROP TABLE Program;

CREATE TABLE Program (
    ProCode       VARCHAR2(12),
    ProTitle      VARCHAR2(50),
    constraint pk_Program PRIMARY KEY (ProCode));
```

Comment: try to copy exactly what I wrote? because it's working for me.. I change the start to CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE , thanks to @gdoron

Comment: If I create the tables one by one it is OK but when I create them at the same time it gets failed again

Comment: You fell in my mistake... [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1008248/601179). Sorry.