# PLS-00103 Error in PL/SQL Developer

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper, create-table, pls-00103

***Note: I do not have this problem when using Oracle SQL Developer:: - But it is not the Standard here. So i must find a way to do this in PL/SQL Developer***

When attempting to use PL/SQL developer (PL/SQL Developer - the program) to dynamically drop tables then create new ones using a create statement I consistently run into the error:
***PLS-00103: ENCOUNTERED  THE SYMBOL "/"  THE SYMBOL "/" WAS IGNORED PLSQL***

This is due to the "/" at the end of the dynamic sql.

If I remove the "/" from the end I receive an error: 
***ENCOUNTERED  THE SYMBOL "CREATE"***

What is the best method to get around this error inside PL/SQL Developer?

Thank You:

```
DECLARE
       VE_TABLENOTEXISTS EXCEPTION;
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(VE_TABLENOTEXISTS, -942);


    PROCEDURE DROPTABLE(PIS_TABLENAME IN VARCHAR2) IS
              VS_DYNAMICDROPTABLESQL VARCHAR2(1024);
                    BEGIN
                       VS_DYNAMICDROPTABLESQL := 'DROP TABLE ' || PIS_TABLENAME;  
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE VS_DYNAMICDROPTABLESQL;

                    EXCEPTION
                        WHEN VE_TABLENOTEXISTS THEN
                             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(PIS_TABLENAME || ' NOT EXIST, SKIPPING....');
                        WHEN OTHERS THEN
                             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
                    RAISE;
                    END DROPTABLE;

    BEGIN
      DROPTABLE('foo.foo_table');
END DROPTABLE;
   /

 CREATE TABLE foo.foo_table AS
(
SELECT STUFF, MORE_STUFF FROM not_foo_table
)
;

SELECT * FROM foo.foo_table
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have too PLSQL Developer.
I try to compile your procedure the way you post it and I get the same error, but if I remove the blank spaces before the "/" it works fine; like it don't recognize the "/".

So, I recommend you to change this:

```
END DROPTABLE;
   /
```

For this:

```
END DROPTABLE;
/
```

Comment: HAHAHA!  Spaces! I've never had spaces in SQl Cause this mus trouble before.